# Springboot caching SerializationException using Redis

Tags: spring-boot, caching, spring-data-redis

I'm trying to make a springboot Redis caching demo.

Here is the Redis configuration class:

```
@Configuration
@EnableCaching
public class RedisConfig extends CachingConfigurerSupport {

    @Value("${custom.config.redis.ttl}")
    private Integer timeTtl;

    @Bean
    public CacheManager cacheManager(RedisConnectionFactory redisConnectionFactory) {
        return new RedisCacheManager(
                RedisCacheWriter.nonLockingRedisCacheWriter(redisConnectionFactory),
                this.getRedisCacheConfigurationWithTtl(timeTtl),
                this.getRedisCacheConfigurationMap()
        );
    }

    private Map<String, RedisCacheConfiguration> getRedisCacheConfigurationMap() {
        Map<String, RedisCacheConfiguration> redisCacheConfigurationMap = new HashMap<>(10);
        redisCacheConfigurationMap
                .put("SsoCache", this.getRedisCacheConfigurationWithTtl(24 * 60 * 60));
        redisCacheConfigurationMap
                .put("BasicDataCache", this.getRedisCacheConfigurationWithTtl(30 * 60));
        return redisCacheConfigurationMap;
    }

    private RedisCacheConfiguration getRedisCacheConfigurationWithTtl(Integer seconds) {
        Jackson2JsonRedisSerializer<Object> jackson2JsonRedisSerializer = new Jackson2JsonRedisSerializer<>(
                Object.class);
        ObjectMapper om = new ObjectMapper();
        om.setVisibility(PropertyAccessor.ALL, JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.ANY);
        om.activateDefaultTyping(BasicPolymorphicTypeValidator.builder().build(),
                ObjectMapper.DefaultTyping.NON_FINAL);
        jackson2JsonRedisSerializer.setObjectMapper(om);
        RedisCacheConfiguration redisCacheConfiguration = RedisCacheConfiguration
                .defaultCacheConfig();
        redisCacheConfiguration = redisCacheConfiguration.serializeValuesWith(
                RedisSerializationContext
                        .SerializationPair
                        .fromSerializer(jackson2JsonRedisSerializer)
        ).entryTtl(Duration.ofSeconds(seconds));

        return redisCacheConfiguration;
    }
}
```

redis service:

```
@Service
@Slf4j
public class RedisService {

    private final StringRedisTemplate redisTemplate;

    public RedisService(StringRedisTemplate redisTemplate) {
        Assert.notNull(redisTemplate, "redisTemplate is required");
        this.redisTemplate = redisTemplate;
    }

    @Cacheable(value = "user", key = "#userRedis.getId()")
    public UserRedis saveUser(UserRedis userRedis) {
        log.trace("user{} is saved", userRedis);
        return userRedis;
    }
}
```

test class:

```
    @SpringBootTest
    class RedisServiceTest {

        @Autowired
        private RedisService redisService;

        @Autowired
        private StringRedisTemplate stringRedisTemplate;

        @Autowired
        private RedisTemplate redisTemplate;

        @Test
        void saveUser() {
            UserRedis japhy = UserRedis.builder().id(3L).name("japhy").age(10L).build();
            UserRedis userRedis = redisService.saveUser(japhy);
            Assertions.assertThat(userRedis).isNotNull();
            Assertions.assertThat(userRedis.getId()).isEqualTo(3L);
            Assertions.assertThat(userRedis.getName()).isEqualTo("japhy");
            Assertions.assertThat(userRedis.getAge()).isEqualTo(10L);
        }
    }
```

model class:

```
    @Builder
    public class UserRedis implements Serializable {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = -1541408164202572383L;
        private Long id;

        private String name;

        private Long age;

        public UserRedis() {
        }

        public UserRedis(Long id, String name, Long age) {
            this.id = id;
            this.name = name;
            this.age = age;
        }

        public Long getId() {
            return id;
        }

        public void setId(Long id) {
            this.id = id;
        }

        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }

        public void setName(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }

        public Long getAge() {
            return age;
        }

        public void setAge(Long age) {
            this.age = age;
        }
    }
```

application.yml:

```
spring:
  redis:
    database: 0
    # Redis服务器地址
    host: 39.99.155.113
    # Redis服务器连接端口
    port: 6379
    # Redis服务器连接密码（默认为空）
    password:
    lettuce:
      pool:
        max-active: 8
        max-wait: -1s
        max-idle: 8
        min-idle: 0
  cache:
    redis:
      time-to-live: 180s #缓存超时时间ms
      cache-null-values: false #是否缓存空值
    type: redis

custom:
  config:
    redis:
      ttl: 1800
```

I can save the modal class to Redis successfully. But when I try to read it from Redis. It throws an exception:

```
org.springframework.data.redis.serializer.SerializationException: Could not read JSON: Could not resolve type id 'com.japhy.examples.model.UserRedis' as a subtype of `java.lang.Object`: Configured `PolymorphicTypeValidator` (of type `com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.jsontype.BasicPolymorphicTypeValidator`) denied resolution
 at [Source: (byte[])"["com.japhy.examples.model.UserRedis",{"id":3,"name":"japhy","age":10}]"; line: 1, column: 39]; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidTypeIdException: Could not resolve type id 'com.japhy.examples.model.UserRedis' as a subtype of `java.lang.Object`: Configured `PolymorphicTypeValidator` (of type `com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.jsontype.BasicPolymorphicTypeValidator`) denied resolution
 at [Source: (byte[])"["com.japhy.examples.model.UserRedis",{"id":3,"name":"japhy","age":10}]"; line: 1, column: 39]

    at org.springframework.data.redis.serializer.Jackson2JsonRedisSerializer.deserialize(Jackson2JsonRedisSerializer.java:75)
    at org.springframework.data.redis.serializer.DefaultRedisElementReader.read(DefaultRedisElementReader.java:48)
    at org.springframework.data.redis.serializer.RedisSerializationContext$SerializationPair.read(RedisSerializationContext.java:272)
    at org.springframework.data.redis.cache.RedisCache.deserializeCacheValue(RedisCache.java:260)
    at org.springframework.data.redis.cache.RedisCache.lookup(RedisCache.java:94)
    at org.springframework.cache.support.AbstractValueAdaptingCache.get(AbstractValueAdaptingCache.java:58)
    at org.springframework.cache.interceptor.AbstractCacheInvoker.doGet(AbstractCacheInvoker.java:73)
    at org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheAspectSupport.findInCaches(CacheAspectSupport.java:554)
    at org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheAspectSupport.findCachedItem(CacheAspectSupport.java:519)
    at org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheAspectSupport.execute(CacheAspectSupport.java:401)
    at org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheAspectSupport.execute(CacheAspectSupport.java:345)
    at org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheInterceptor.invoke(CacheInterceptor.java:61)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:747)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:689)
    at com.japhy.examples.RedisService$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$e0f4e77a.saveUser(<generated>)
    at com.japhy.examples.RedisServiceTest.saveUser(RedisServiceTest.java:32)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.junit.platform.commons.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:675)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.MethodInvocation.proceed(MethodInvocation.java:60)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain$ValidatingInvocation.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:125)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.intercept(TimeoutExtension.java:132)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.interceptTestableMethod(TimeoutExtension.java:124)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.interceptTestMethod(TimeoutExtension.java:74)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker$ReflectiveInterceptorCall.lambda$ofVoidMethod$0(ExecutableInvoker.java:115)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.lambda$invoke$0(ExecutableInvoker.java:105)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain$InterceptedInvocation.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:104)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:62)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.chainAndInvoke(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:43)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.invoke(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:35)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.invoke(ExecutableInvoker.java:104)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.invoke(ExecutableInvoker.java:98)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeTestMethod$6(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:202)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.invokeTestMethod(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:198)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:135)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:69)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:135)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:125)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:135)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:123)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:122)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:80)
    at java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1249)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:38)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:125)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:135)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:123)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:122)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:80)
    at java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1249)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:38)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:125)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:135)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:123)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:122)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:80)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.submit(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:32)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:57)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestEngine.execute(HierarchicalTestEngine.java:51)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:229)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.lambda$execute$6(DefaultLauncher.java:197)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.withInterceptedStreams(DefaultLauncher.java:211)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:191)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:128)
    at com.intellij.junit5.JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.java:69)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:33)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:230)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:58)
Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidTypeIdException: Could not resolve type id 'com.japhy.examples.model.UserRedis' as a subtype of `java.lang.Object`: Configured `PolymorphicTypeValidator` (of type `com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.jsontype.BasicPolymorphicTypeValidator`) denied resolution
 at [Source: (byte[])"["com.japhy.examples.model.UserRedis",{"id":3,"name":"japhy","age":10}]"; line: 1, column: 39]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidTypeIdException.from(InvalidTypeIdException.java:43)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.invalidTypeIdException(DeserializationContext.java:1758)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DatabindContext._throwSubtypeClassNotAllowed(DatabindContext.java:291)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DatabindContext.resolveAndValidateSubType(DatabindContext.java:248)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.jsontype.impl.ClassNameIdResolver._typeFromId(ClassNameIdResolver.java:72)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.jsontype.impl.ClassNameIdResolver.typeFromId(ClassNameIdResolver.java:66)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.jsontype.impl.TypeDeserializerBase._findDeserializer(TypeDeserializerBase.java:156)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.jsontype.impl.AsArrayTypeDeserializer._deserialize(AsArrayTypeDeserializer.java:97)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.jsontype.impl.AsArrayTypeDeserializer.deserializeTypedFromAny(AsArrayTypeDeserializer.java:71)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.UntypedObjectDeserializer$Vanilla.deserializeWithType(UntypedObjectDeserializer.java:712)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.impl.TypeWrappedDeserializer.deserialize(TypeWrappedDeserializer.java:68)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._readMapAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:4202)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:3309)
    at org.springframework.data.redis.serializer.Jackson2JsonRedisSerializer.deserialize(Jackson2JsonRedisSerializer.java:73)
    ... 79 more
```

I have read the Spring document in https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-redis/docs/current/reference/html/#redis:serializer. But still have no idea how to fix the problem.
Any advice? thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As deprecated method is still available, we can stole the implementation from there :)
This is how it looks in my code now:

```
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
objectMapper.activateDefaultTyping(LaissezFaireSubTypeValidator.instance , DefaultTyping.NON_FINAL, JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY);
```

The main point here is `LaissezFaireSubTypeValidator.instance`, cause it creates the necessary `PolymorphicTypeValidator`.